# Is it possible to send an array with the Postman Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, rest, post

I've been using Postman Chrome extension to test out my API and would like to send an array of IDs via post. Is there a way to send something list this as a parameter in Postman?

```
{
  user_ids: ["1234", "5678"]
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain the right way to send an array is "in some way that the *particular* server you are sending it to will receive it correctly".  This accounts for the variation in answers below - but it'd all be a bit more useful if everyone (or anyone?) had said what back-end they were using.

Answer (score 630, accepted):

You need to suffix your variable name with `[]` like this:

[image: send_array_param_with_postman]

If that doesn't work, try not putting indexes in brackets:

```
my_array[]  value1
my_array[]  value2
```

---

**Note:**

- If you are using the [postman packaged app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), you can send an array by selecting `raw` / `json` (instead of `form-data`). Also, make sure to set `Content-Type` as `application/json` in `Headers` tab. 
  Here is example for raw data `{"user_ids": ["123"  "233"]}`, don't forget the quotes!
- If you are using the [postman REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) you have to use the method I described above because passing data as raw (json) won't work. There is a bug in the postman REST client (At least I get the bug when I use `0.8.4.6`).

Comment: Just in case someone is asking how to add hashes instead of just array, the idea is still the same, just change the indexes to hash name `my_array[hashname] value1`

Comment: `my_array[] value` will create a array parameter with the values provided, as `key => [value`].
`my_array[key] value` will create a hash, as `{key => value}`.

Comment: none of them worked but I figured out just adding the array name works in 2019. [http://prntscr.com/nqubpi]

Comment: Your 2nd option without index, solved my issue, Thanks

Answer (score 96):

For me did not work with array[0], array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOnKu.jpg), .. or array[], array[], ... .
It works more simply:
[image]

Comment: By adding multiple keys with same name, the server will receive the last one only

Comment: please tell me how to send only one element userid[0] in form-data. if i pass userid[]/userid[0] in a key field it taken as a string!

Comment: with asp.net core 2.2, it receives all array elements with this solution

Comment: in Django I was able to get all files with: request.FILES.getlist('usersId'), using this method

Answer (score 75):

If you want an array of dicts, try this:
[image]

Comment: For me what worked for node.js / mongoose is ```social_links[0].name``` notice the additional **period**

Comment: In your example what if `name` is also an array? I tried something like `social_links[0]name[0]` in Django REST Framework (nested writable model-serializer with many-to-many relations) and it didn't work.

Comment: As long as I add a '.'  after the index (e.g. social_liks[0].name) this works for me from Postman using Spring Rest.

Comment: unfortunately, social_link[0].name doesn't work for me , when I check postman body request it shows "social_link[0].name" = "136" do you've any Idea why ?

Comment: how to create a custom request for for this in laravel 8 ?

Comment: For laravel, social_link[0][name] should work

Answer (score 60):

Here is my solution:

use form-data and edit as below:

```
Key       Value 
box[]      a
box[n1]    b
box[n2][]  c
box[n2][]  d
```

and you will get an array like this:

```
{"box":{"0":"a","n1":"b","n2":["c","d"]}}
```

Comment: Great! finally I can send a object
        "loc": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                126.972967,
                37.54171
            ],
        }  to type in  loc[type]: Point, loc[coordinates][] :126..., loc[coordinates][]: 37... on Postman thx!!

Comment: This is very helpful as when you need to send files, the 'raw' format of Postman just won't work. You need to use the form-data format.

Comment: The only down drawback of this solution is that if you use number as a key, the blank one will be the last key. array[0], array[1], array[], the blank one will be array[2]

Answer (score 40):

It is important to know, that the VALUE box is only allowed to contain a numeral value (no specifiers).

If you want to send e.g. an array of "messages" with Postman, each having a list of key/value pairs, enter e.g. messages[][reason] into the KEY box and the value of reason into the VALUE box:

[image]

The server will receive:

```
{"messages"=>[{"reason"=>"scrolled", "tabid"=>"2"}, {"reason"=>"reload", "tabid"=>"1"}], "endpoint"=>{}}
```

Comment: This did the trick... but only when I checked form-data option.

Answer (score 37):

I also had that problem, and solved it by doing the following:

1 - Going to the request header configuration and added the following:

```
Accept : application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type : application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

2 - To send the json array, I went to raw json format and set the user_ids to array:

```
user_ids: ["bbbbbbbbbb","aaaaaaaaaa","987654321","123456789"]
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, setting the Accept header was not necessary however

Comment: This was the answer I needed.

Comment: My API method expects List<string> and this did the job.

Answer (score 30):

Set Body as raw and form the array as follows:

[image]

Comment: {
 "question" : "What is capital of India",
 "marks" : 1,
 "options" : [
  "Mumbai",
  "Pune",
  "New Delhi",
  "Jaipur"
 ],
 "correct" : "New Delhi"
}

Answer (score 24):

As mentioned by @pinouchon you can pass it with the help of array index

```
my_array[0] value
my_array[1] value

In addition to this, to pass list of hashes, you can follow something like:

my_array[0][key1] value1

my_array[0][key2] value2
```

***Example:***

```
To pass param1=[{name:test_name, value:test_value}, {...}]

param1[0][name] test_name

param1[0][value] test_value
```

Comment: This worked for me. Since, i also needed to send image file in request, along with array of object this is what i needed. There is no way to send the image file in raw format(json)

Answer (score 19):

Go to Header and select `Content-Type` = `application/json` then go to body and select `raw` and then pass an array.[image]

Answer (score 17):

this worked for me. to pass an array of Item object {ItemID,ColorID,SizeID,Quntity}

[image: Postman data]

Answer (score 10):

in headers set

```
content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

In body select option

> x-www-form-urlencoded

and insert data as json array

```
user_ids : ["1234", "5678"]
```

Comment: Only one that worked for me using form data! Couldn't use raw since I'm sending images too

Comment: The only one worked for me as well 

For complete newbies: Press x-www-form-urlencoded => bulk edit => UserNames:["UserName1","UserName2", "UserName3"]

Answer (score 10):

**In form-data you can pass a array like this**

[image]

and in backend you will fetch it like a

```
"tags"=>["aaaa", "bbb"]
```

In my case I've to pass two values in a array so I write it two times

Answer (score 9):

This also works for lists within the object:

```
Id:37
IdParent:26
Name:Poplet
Values[0].Id:1349
Values[0].Name:SomeName
Values[1].Id:1350
Values[1].Name:AnotherName
```

the equivalent JSON would be:

```
{
    "Id": 37,
    "IdParent": 26,
    "Name": "Poplet",
    "Values": [
        {
            "Id": 1349,
            "Name": "SomeName"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1350,
            "Name": "AnotherName"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, Values[0].Id doesn't work for me , when I check postman body request it shows "Values[0].Id" = "1349" do you've any Idea why ?

Answer (score 9):

```
{
    "data" : [  
        {
            "key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2"   
        },
        {
            "key01" : "value01",
            "key02" : "value02"             
        },
        {
            "key10" : "value10",
            "key20" : "value20"   
        }
    ]
}
```

You can pass like this.

Answer (score 6):

Choose either form-data or urlencoded and use the same key "user_ids". The server should receive it as an array.

Comment: Looks like, due to a bug in Chrome that erroneously sends with an XML header even when you select JSON in Postman, you have to add a `Content-type` header with value `application/json`.

Comment: just in case someone comes back looking for an answer, the key for an array should be user_ids[] instead of just user_ids

Answer (score 6):

##### Request header configuration and added the following

```
Accept: application/json
```

##### You need to suffix your key variable name with **[]**

> `like` key[0][name]

[image]

##### You can insert it in "bulk-edit" mode

Body section in form-data on right side click Bulk Edit and added the following

```
items[0][prod_id]:174336
items[0][item_weight]:3.400
items[0][item_qty]:1
items[0][item_selected_melting]:92
items[0][item_remarks]:
items[1][prod_id]:12345
```

Answer (score 5):

In form-data,

```
   key              value

 user_ids[]         1234
 user_ids[]         5678
```

Answer (score 5):

My back-end is written in Ruby on Rails. This is how I sent the array params using Postman. It worked for me.

**UPDATE**

I'm using *x-www-form-urlencoded*. I believe it will work too for *form-data*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case I need to send array of objects, I sent it like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To send an array using form data there's no need to use brackets.
Just send that specific array using the same name in multiple fields.

Like:

```
my_array:value_1
my_array:value_2
```

Comment: Please double check your understanding of the difference of "answer" and "question". ;-) Harmless mistake of course.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has already accepted a solution still that solution has a drawback that is we have to repeat the key (Array name) again and again as one key is accepting only one value. Like this:

[image: Postman form-data (Key-Value Pairs)]

Imagine we have 10 values or more, should we repeat the same Array name each time? The programmatic answer is **NO**. Then we should do the following that is a better approach.

1. Select the form-data as usual
2. Type Array name in the Key field
3. Pass the Array in Value field

Like this:

[image: Passing Array in Postman]

Now, you should be able to send the Array, but wait, this won't be stored in Database like that in my case with MongoDB. So what you have to do is, use the following piece of code to send it like an Array in the Database:

1. First, we need to parse it using JSON, like this

`let user_ids = JSON.parse(body.user_ids);`

2. Now, you can send `user_ids` variable to database like an Array

That's All!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solution here and in other posts, but nothing helped.

The only answer helped me:
Adding [FromBody] attribute before decleration of parameter in function signature:

```
[Route("MyFunc")]        
public string MyFunc([FromBody] string[] obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have the array of object below,

```
features: [
      {
        title: { type: String },
        type: { type: String },
      },
    ],
```

To add the values on the form data on the postman, add it this way

```
features[title]
features[type]
```

Check also the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that worked for me

```
{
 "user_ids":["[1234, 5678]"]
}
```

I believe it depends on how the backend is setup most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

**N.B** Now we are in 2022 if All of the above solutions didn't, just don't panic. pass array name with is value without a bracket and the add it multiple time, just link how the image below is showing. it should work just fine. If It does work, buy me some coffee, hhh

[image]

Comment: It will not work. It will fetch the tag2 value

Comment: @manishnautiyal have you tried it? because that is the way I only use to pass array data and it works as expected

Comment: Yes, I try and it didn't work for me so I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it!

[image: Form-data request in postman]

Add the array you want to add above, and then on the backend side Simply Parse it, In my case, since I want an array of User Ref, I have typecast it into The object of user.

[image: Parsing the data]