# How to make POST request to send array through Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

I used Postman plugin for Chrome to send request and get response, but this plugin didn't allow (or I couldn't do) to send request with array, but I need it. Please, give me advice, which plugin can I use for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to send an array with the Postman Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 6):

To send an array you need to set the same request key as "my_array[]" and then add your values. Postman let's you do this already.

Answer (score 2):

@Abhinav is right. For the lazy:

[image: send_array_param_with_postman]

If that doesn't work, try not putting indexes in brackets:

```
my_array[]  value1
my_array[]  value2
```

Answer (score 2):

For me did not work with array[0], array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOnKu.jpg), .. or array[], array[], ... .
It works more simply:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed an array of objets.

That's what it worked for me[image]