# How to use postman to test formdata?

Tags: json, forms, postman

How can I use postman plugin of Google Chrome to send a FormData() object to a webapi using POST. The FormData() object has form fields personID and messageBody appended to it. I tried something like this but to no avail:

```
URL of the webapi: http://localhost/<<appName>>/api/v1/message

Headers:
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=---XXX---

form-data:
personID:1 (Text)   
messageBody:Hello (Text)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes finally I have made it work. What I was doing wrong was not setting all the fields of the FormData() object ie, I didn't set the fields such as orderId because its value was null. When I set all the field values even if they were null, it worked. And also there was no need to set the Content-Type when you are sending a multipart/form-data...

Answer (score 30):

Postman has a form-data POST body option that automatically does this for you.