# Postman chrome extension with array of hashes as value

Tags: google-chrome-app, postman

I have a data that looks like this:[image: json data]

I took a look at this post [Array value on postman chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension), so I know how to use postman to send post request with parameters from `age` to `skillset`, my problem is the `work_experience`, it's an array of hashes, I want to input the `work_experience` in postman, from which you can see is an array of hashes.

So is this possible? And if you know a better chrome extension that can do this, feel free to answer or comment

**P.S.**

Although this is should be obvious, but for the sake of the person who voted to close this for being **unclear**, my purpose is to simulate what my mobile ios app would send to my server's api without actually using the ios app to type on every textfield every time I run the app.

Comment: For alternatives: http://superuser.com/questions/345034/google-chrome-extension-to-submit-post-get-requests

Comment: Can you please be more specific or explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean what am I trying to achieve? I believe I supplied enough information for my question "Postman chrome extension with array of hashes as value", along with the description and an image of my data. If you know the google chrome's postman rest extension, you wouldn't need to ask, and if you also checked the link I included, you would also be able to see what the postman does :|

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can put nested sub-keys in brackets. So you could define some of your key/value pairs in the form-data fields like this:

```
key: work_experience[0][company_name] 
value: asdfdfaf

key: work_experience[0][end_date] 
value: 12/21/2121

key: work_experience[1][company_name]
value: fdjfkjdfjk

key: work_experience[1][end_date]
value: 1/3/15
```

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try you sending it as a "raw" data" (and not a form-data or form-urlencoded)

Answer (score 1):

U can also try as below... its worked for me

key: work_experience[0].company_name 
value: asdfdfaf

key: work_experience[0].end_date
value: 12/21/2121

key: work_experience[1].company_name
value: fdjfkjdfjk

key: work_experience[1][end_date]
value: 1/3/15

Answer (score 1):

You can send the data by choosing the `raw` option in `Body` and `Content-Type` as `application/json` in `headers` in postman's `POST` request option. This is how you can form the data while sending it -

```
{ "work_experience": [{"company_name": "asd", "end_date": "12/12/2121", 
                      "leave_reason": "asdasdasd", "position": "asdasd", 
                      "start_date": "12/12/2012"}]
}
```