# Can I send 2 dimension array as parameter in POSTMAN?

Tags: arrays, postman

I need to send parameters as array of objects in POSTMAN.

```
"array": [
    {"field1": "html", "field2": "5"},
    {"field1": "css", "field2": "3"}
 ]
```

I know that array must send as `array[]` but how can I set one item of the array as an object?

I tried this

```
"array[]" : "{"field1": "html", "field2": "5"}"
```

But I'm getting a `500` response error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postman chrome extension with array of hashes as value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239042/postman-chrome-extension-with-array-of-hashes-as-value)

Comment: @Xan Thank you for respond.
I've tried to use:
array[0][field1]      html
array[0][field2]      5
But got error 500

Comment: I think it will help for u<br/>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]Just send it in raw format(in json) and specify data type as application/json. Worked for me

Comment: Yep, it could be used also

Comment: The requirement is to send the data as form-data and not with raw data. The reason behind this: To support existing code. If you know how I can send this data in form-data then please let me know.

Answer (score 11):

If array of arrays works for you as well, you can send them like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to **bulk edit**

```
userdata:[{"name":"name1","email":"email1@gmail.com"},{"name":"name2","email":"email2@gmail.com"},{"name":"name3","email":"email3@gmail.com"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution adding raw data as `JSON`.
from `body > raw`

```
[
  {
    "text": "Buy fish",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "text": "Go for walk check",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "text": "Pick baby from school",
    "completed": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this ia an old post but this might help someone out there.... it's what worked for me:

In your controller: (Laravel/PHP)

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'fields' => 'nullable|array|min:1',
'fields.key1.*' => 'integer',
'fields.key2.*' => 'integer'
]);

if ($validator->fails())
{
return ...
}
```

Then in Postman:

```
fields[0]['key1']
fields[0]['key2']
```

.... and you can repeat this as many times as you need to, just increment the index

```
fields[1]['key1']
fields[1]['key2']
```

If you dd(fields) in your controller, you'd get:

```
0 => [
      key1 => value1
      key2 => value2
]

1 => [
      key1 => value3
      key2 => value4
]
```

.....