# Postman form-data passing two dimensional array

Tags: go, postman

here is my request structure

```
type Request struct {
   Workplace [][]int `json:"workplace" form:"workplace[][]"
}
```

and Content-Type: multipart/form-data

How can i get data by using Postman form-data?

Expected Receiving Result As :-

```
Workplace = [[1,2] [2,3] [4,5]]
```

I attached my postman form-data screenshot here
[image: POSTMAN Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I send 2 dimension array as parameter in POSTMAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032483/can-i-send-2-dimension-array-as-parameter-in-postman)

Comment: @Inian is similar to the question.. but is not the same.
I referred to your post and tried on my way.
and I still don't find for the solution yet