# Mongoose - Save array of strings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I can't save an array of strings into my DB using `Mongoose`.

(Note all code below is simplified for ease of writing here)

So i declare a variable of a person schema I have:

```
var newPerson = new Person ({
    tags: req.body.tags
});
```

The schema itself looks like:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: Array
});
```

And when it comes to saving its just a simple:

```
newPerson.save(function(err) {
    //basic return of json
});
```

So using Postman I send in an array in the body - however everytime I check the DB, it just shows one entry with the array as a whole i.e. how I sent it:

[image]

Any ideas what extra I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Does this work? - `var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: [{type: String}]
});`

Comment: What about just: `var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: [String]
});`

Comment: Unfortunately not that either

Comment: Are you sure that `req.body.tags` is an array? try doing - `console.log(typeof req.body.tags)` or `Array.isArray(req.body.tags)`

Comment: Ahh! - it's a String. Good spot
So whats wrong with that in Postman `['people', 'players']`?

Comment: Try see if this work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension - if it does work let me know and I'll write it up in an answer.

Comment: Not having luck with that at the moment but at least I'm in the right direction. WIll continue searhcing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try your initial request with postman but select 'raw' instead of form-data, and then click 'text' and swap it to JSON like in this screenshot - https://imgur.com/4n3Zfep

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Write up from my comment:

The way to specify an array of strings in mongoose is like so:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
tags: [{
    type: String
}]
```

However, the problem here is most-likely to do with Postman as it is sending the 'array' as a string. You can check this by checking the type of `req.body.tags` like so:

```
console.log(typeof req.body.tags)
```

If this returns a String,  make sure to set the content-type in Postman to JSON as seen in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG2og.jpg) screenshot rather than the default 'form-data' option.

Comment: The issue is with Postman not taking my array as an array but rather a string

Comment: Indeed, hopefully setting the content-type will fix it. You could always pad it within an object and send it as a JSON object.

Answer (score 64):

```
var schema = new Schema({
  name:    String,
  binary:  Buffer,
  living:  Boolean,
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  age:     { type: Number, min: 18, max: 65 },
  mixed:   Schema.Types.Mixed,
  _someId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  decimal: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
  array: [],
  ofString: [String],
  ofNumber: [Number],
  ofDates: [Date],
  ofBuffer: [Buffer],
  ofBoolean: [Boolean],
  ofMixed: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
  ofObjectId: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
  ofArrays: [[]],
  ofArrayOfNumbers: [[Number]],
  nested: {
    stuff: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true }
  },
  map: Map,
  mapOfString: {
    type: Map,
    of: String
  }
})

// example use

var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', schema);

var m = new Thing;
m.name = 'Statue of Liberty';
m.age = 125;
m.updated = new Date;
m.binary = Buffer.alloc(0);
m.living = false;
m.mixed = { any: { thing: 'i want' } };
m.markModified('mixed');
m._someId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
m.array.push(1);
m.ofString.push("strings!");
m.ofNumber.unshift(1,2,3,4);
m.ofDates.addToSet(new Date);
m.ofBuffer.pop();
m.ofMixed = [1, [], 'three', { four: 5 }];
m.nested.stuff = 'good';
m.map = new Map([['key', 'value']]);
m.save(callback);
```

Comment: Tried everything I could but its still showing Array key with no data. (Empty array key)

Answer (score 15):

1. On Schema: 
   ( Since you have mentioned in the problem that it is an *array of strings* )

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags:{
     type:[String],
     required: true
  }
});
```

2. On Postman:

```
{
  "tags": ["css", "javascript", "mongoose", "node"]
}
```

3. On MongoDB

```
{
  "tags":["css", "javascript", "mongoose", "node"]
}
```

Similarly, you can create other types of primitive arrays and document arrays in the mongoose schema as:

```
({
  toys: [ToySchema],
  buffers: [Buffer],
  strings: [String],
  numbers: [Number]
  // ... etc
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Try changing the schema to

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: [{type: String}]
});
```

or you can use Mixed type

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

**EDIT**

i think the problem is with assignment. Use:

```
person.tags.push("string to push");
```

Comment: if this didn't work then i think the problem is somewhere else, not in the schema

Answer (score 4):

1. On Schema

   `techs: Array`
2. On Postman

   `"techs": ["express","rect","html","css","scss"]`
3. On DB (MongoDB)

   `"techs" : [ 
       "epxress", 
       "rect", 
       "html", 
       "css", 
       "scss"
   ]`

Answer (score 3):

My requirement;
ingredients: Type Array of Strings

Solution:

```
ingredients: {
    type: [String],
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: [{type: String}]
});
```

Use this in the schema.

Saving the Array:

```
var etc = new modename({yourprimaryid: primaryid});
                        for (var i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
                            etc.tag.push(tag[i]);
                        }
                        etc.save(function(err) {
                          //whatever you want here
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth Ajmera

Comment: @userMod2 Post other codes as well in that case because schema problem shouldn't be there. I actually use Express Mongoose (Mongo) and I have used similar system.

Comment: I just copied some of my code here, I had to edit major chunk of it. Please check if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Define a Schema:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  tags: [String]
});
```

In postman add each element separately using the array syntax below

```
name:Thing
tags[]:task
tags[]:other
tags[]:thing
```

Return Data:

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "Thing",
    "_id": "5a96e8d0c7b7d1323c677b33",
    "tags": [
        "task",
        "other",
        "thing"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this will also work

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    tags: {
        type: [String], default: []
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a simialr problem,
In the model, do this :

```
tags : {[String], default: undefined}
```

So that it defaults to undefined unstead of an empty array,
and instead of this:

```
const person = new Person({
    tags : req.body.tags
});
```

Do this :

```
const person = new Person();
person.tags = req.body.tags;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as many people have noted, the schema needs to change to indicate that the `tags` field is intended to hold an array of strings, and not just a single one.  So that needs to change to:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: [String]
});
```

The other thing you need to keep in mind (and which caused me a lot of trouble), is that when saving, make sure to use a fresh array for the `tags` field.  For example, this **won't** work:

```
person.tags[0] = "new tag";
person.save();
```

Instead, you need to do something like:

```
person.tags = person.tags.slice(); // Clone the tags array
person.tags[0] = "new tag";
person.save();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no need to slice the array.  Mongoose has built in methods for adding elements to a document's array.  using `.push()` will work just fine.  See here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-array-js

Answer (score 0):

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
    price: {
      type: String,
    },
    categoryId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
    },
    sellerId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Seller",
    },
    discount: {
      type: String,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      default: "active",
      enum: ["active", "inactive", "deleted"],
    },
    images: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use an array of strings in postgres is:

`someFieldName: [String]`