# sub document array saving using mongoose creates empty array MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I am very new to mongo db and mongoose. I am having a problem when tried to save schema with sub document arrays. Sub documents are saved as blanks.
I tried reading many solutions in the net but couldn't find/identify the suitable one as I am pretty new to this.

here is my code snippet of schema js and router js,

### schema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AppEntitySchema1 = new Schema({
    name : {type:String, unique:true},
    appName: String,
    entries : [{
        value : String,
        synonyms:[{String}]
    }]
});

const AppEntitySchema = mongoose.model('entity',AppEntitySchema1);   
module.exports = AppEntitySchema;
```

### router.js

```
// load the Entity model
var Entity = require('../models/entity');

// expose the routes to our app with module.exports

module.exports = function(app) {

    // create entity and send back all entities after creation
    app.post('/api/entities', function(req, res) {

        let model = new Entity(req.body);
        model.save(function(err,createdObject){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
                res.send(createdObject);
        })
    });
}
```

[image: Output :]
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509611/mongoose-save-array-of-strings):

```
const AppEntitySchema1 = new Schema({
    name : {type:String, unique:true},
    appName: String,
    entries : [{
        value : String,
        synonyms:[{
          type: String
      }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: actually i changed it to synonyms : [String] , of course what you suggested is also same. It's working fine. Thank you dude