# Saving an array of strings using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to save this data in my `mongodb` database:

```js
var Student_Answers = {
  matricNumber: matric,
  Answers:  answers  //This is the array answers = ["A", "B"]
};
```

This is my schema:

```js
var Student_AnswersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  matricNumber: String,
  Answers: [
    {
      type: String
    }
  ]
});
```

And this is where the save function is fired

```js
var save = SA(req.body).save(function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.json(data);
});
```

The matric appears in the database and also the array name but never the contents of the array

[image]

Comment: you are saving ```  Answers:  answers  //This is the array ["A", "B"]
``` is array needs to be array of object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose - Save array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509611/mongoose-save-array-of-strings)

Comment: that is the same thing i did in the code, didnt still work

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(req.body.Answers)` and `console.log(typeof req.body.Answers)` ?

Comment: it logged undefined

Comment: this is what the req.body is looking like:  {
  matricNumber: '22/5698',
  'Answers[]': [ 'A', 'B' ]
}

Comment: you have an extra `[]` with the `Answers` property, what happens if you try with: `const { matricNumber, 'Answers[]': Answers } = req.body; SA({ matricNumber, Answers }).save...` ?

Comment: This worked thank you very much, but can you also explain to me why this worked and not the other way.

Comment: the name of the property in the schema is `Answers` but it's `Answers[]` in the body and `'Answers' != 'Answers[]'`

Comment: but why is it saving as 'Answers[]' in the body

Comment: I don't know, maybe look at the place where you created the request