# Pass Array of string to MongoDb Schema

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to pass my array of string to my schema. As you can see in auth.js **image:image** here I am passing my image array to my mongodb property image and i am getting array of strings successfully in **image** but I tried everything like **$push, $each** but i don't know how to pass the image array to my Mongodb schema. I hope you understand my query.

**Schema.js**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const mySchema=mongoose.Schema({
    
    image:{
        type:[String],
        required:true,
        value:[String]
    }
    
})


const MyCattle=mongoose.model('cattle_list',mySchema);
```

**auth.js**

```
const finaldata = new MyCattle({
        image:[image]
    })
    
    module.exports=MyCattle;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store images in a MongoDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongodb-database)

Comment: I don't want to store images. I want to pass array of strings which contains images names.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509611/mongoose-save-array-of-strings), but I shall share the answer here:

```js
const mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    image: {
        type: [{ type: String }]
    }
});

// ...
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still showing me the error i.e ( ValidationError: 
image.0: Cast to [string] failed for value "[{"image":["sprat (2).jpg"]}]" at path "image.0" )