# How to send only form data in retrofit2 android.

Tags: android, retrofit2

How to send only form data in retrofit2 android.
I have form data like key will be category and value will be some integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit 2 with only form-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814857/retrofit-2-with-only-form-data)

Comment: No that is for Multipart i want only for form data

Comment: You can find a tutorial with various form options and parameters here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your retrofit interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("yourPath")
    Call<YourResponseClass> callApi(@Field("category") int category_value);
```