# Using Retrofit POST with different interface models in callback and body

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Here is my API end point:

```
http://192.168.1.22:8000/api/auth/login
```

I need to `POST`  `email` and `password` to receive `Token` from server

Server Post response:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL21vbmV5bWF0Y2guYXBwOjgwMDBcL2FwaVwvYXV0aFwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0OTE0OTYzNDEsImV4cCI6MTQ5MTQ5OTk0MSwibmJmIjoxNDkxNDk2MzQxLCJqdGkiOiJhZmJhMDEzMzI5OWIwZmY0MzY3MTdlZDE4NmVkODI4OSJ9.bGlInsHHjdveeabz0j_36yICZtK32q1B9oNW44dk_x4"
}
```

here is my service `Retrofit 2`:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("auth/login")
    Call<Login> authenticate(@Body User user);
}
```

here is my `Login Model`

```
public class Login {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    private String token;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

here is my `User Model`:

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;

@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;

public User(String email, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

and this is how i call it in Activity

```
public void sendNetworkRequest(User user){
    Log.d(TAG,"send request fired");
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.22:8000/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Login> call = apiInterface.authenticate(user);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "wuhuuu"+ response.body().getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG,"went wrong");
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "something went wront"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATED:** this is the **Error** I get:

```
com.google.gson.stream.malformedjsonexception use jsonreader.setlenient(true) to accept malformed at line 1column 1 $path
```

**UPDATE Note**: the `email` and `password` need to be sent in body `form data`.

**Note**: I can access the API from browser in Emulator so i guess it means there is something wrong in my logic or approach.

**Complete Stack trace:**

```
 D/LoginActivity: went wrong
        com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1567)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1416)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:597)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:429)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:201)
            at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
            at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
            at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116)
            at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
            at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:106)
            at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
            at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: `.baseUrl("http://129.168.1.22:8000/api/")` did you find the mistake in url?

Comment: Your base url is `http://129.168.1.22:8000/api/`. But the error shows `192.168.1.22`. Is it somewhat wrong ?

Comment: @ArkarAung thanks i updated the error

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati thanks i updated the error

Comment: It may be possible that your received json is not correct.  Please paste complete stack trace.

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati added the complete stack trace

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati i have seen lots of people sending object in body. but in all examples they receive the callback with the same Model class they used in body. can that causing the issue ? PS. in PostMan i use Form Data to add the email and password. is adding to body as an object similar to `Form Data` or is there different way to do that?

Comment: Most of the time email and passwords are sent in auth headers.

Comment: refer this to send form data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814857/retrofit-2-with-only-form-data

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati that was the solution. thanks. If you like to post as answer  I'll mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send form data using Retrofit 2.0

```
@Multipart
@POST("url")
Call<PlanResponse> authenticate(@Part("email") RequestBody eamilValue, @Part("password") RequestBody passwordValue);
```

use it like this:

```
String email = "email@mail.com";
String password = "password";
RequestBody emailValue = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), emailValue);
RequestBody passwordValue= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), passwordValue);
Call<Login> call = apiInterface.authenticate(emailValue,passwordValue);
```