# android retrofit send array as x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, android-networking

I'm using retrofit as my network library, and I want to send a JSON array as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but I don't know how to do that.

Here is my request API :

```
@POST("book")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<BookTicket> BookFlight(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                             @Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
                             @Field("rootType") Integer rootType ,
                             @Field("BookingStep2")  ArrayList<JSONObject> BookingStep2
            );
```

Here is a sample request :

```
{
  "rootType": 1,
  "BookingStep2": {
    "OriginFlightSegment": {
      "FlightNumber": "sample",
      "Source": "sample",
      "TotalTime": "sample",
      "FareDatas": [
        {
          "PassengerType": 1,
          "Endorsements": "sample",
          "FareBasisCode": "sample"
        },
        {
          "PassengerType": 1,
          "Endorsements": "sample",
          "FareBasisCode": "sample"
        }
      ]
      }
    }
 }
```

Is it right to send JSON array as field in retrofit?

Answer (score 3):

To post array object as form-url_encoded just use this in retrofit.

```
@POST(ApiConstants.JOB_CARD_SAVE)
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<MasterResponse<JobCardSaveResponse>> jobCardSave(@FieldMap Map<String, Object> _jobCardRequest,
                                                      @Field("qty[]") List<String> qty,
                                                      @Field("service_id[]") List<String> service_id);
```

Just put your array object in @field.