# Retrofit - Send request body as array or number

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2 and I need to send request body. The problem is somehow the value is converted to string. On the example below, you can see that `items` and `totalPrice` which should be array and number respectively are converted to string.

```
{ cashierId: 'fff7079c-3fc2-453e-99eb-287521feee63',
  items: '[{"amount":3,"id":"602a79e3-b4c1-4161-a082-92202f92d1d6","name":"Play Station Portable","price":1500000.0}]',
  paymentMethod: 'Debt',
  totalPrice: '4500000.0' }
```

The desired request body is

```
{ cashierId: 'fff7079c-3fc2-453e-99eb-287521feee63',
  items: [{"amount":3,"id":"602a79e3-b4c1-4161-a082-92202f92d1d6","name":"Play Station Portable","price":1500000.0}],
  paymentMethod: 'Debt',
  totalPrice: 4500000.0 }
```

Here's the service

```
@POST("api/sales")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Sale> createSale(
    @FieldMap Map<String, Object> fields
);
```

And this is how I call `createSale`

```
Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
fields.put("cashierId", UUID.fromString("fff7079c-3fc2-453e-99eb-287521feeaaa"));
fields.put("totalPrice", totalPrice);
fields.put("paymentMethod", paymentMethod);
fields.put("items", jsonArray);

Call<Sale> call = retailService.createSale(fields);
```

Is it possible to send those values as number and array, not as string?

Comment: There is a reason why you are sending a Map and not using a POJO?

Comment: First: how does you `jsonArray` look like?
Second: have you tried changing `@FieldMap` to `@RequestBody` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion most certainly happens because you are using `@FormUrlEncoded`.
According to the [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/FormUrlEncoded.html):

> Field names and values will be UTF-8 encoded before being URI-encoded in accordance to RFC-3986.

A solution would be to use a model class instead of a `Map`. I see you already have a Sale class. If it looks like something like this:

```
public class Sale {
    String cashierId;
    int totalPrice;
    String paymentMethod;
    ArrayList<SomeObject> items;
}
```

you can simply do like this:

```
// in service
@POST("api/sales")
Call<Sale> createSale(@Body Sale sale);

// when doing the call
Sale sale = new Sale();
// set everything in your object
// then
Call<Sale> call = retailService.createSale(sale);
```