# Retrofit2 pass array in body

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

How to do this post request in retrofit2?

```
curl --location --request POST "http://localhost/projectjcms/api/search-result" \
  --header "accessToken: eyJ0eOiJK 3ZN_ud117ZPLSQMC0ry-tGUfOmLvgsLqRQIA" \
  --header "lang: 1" \
  --header "Content-Type: text/plain" \
  --form "property_type[0]=1" \
  --form "property_type[1]=2" \
  --form "bedroom_type[0]=1" \
  --form "bedroom_type[1]=5" \
  --form "bedroom_type[2]=3"
```

> RequestBody unitDetailsRequestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
>                               .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
>                               .addFormDataPart("property_id[0]", "3")
>                               //.addFormDataPart("property_id[1]", "2")
>                               .build();

```
   // @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/search-result")
    Call<Frame> getSearchResult(@Header("accessToken") String accessToken,
                                @Header("lang") int language,
                                @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                                @Body String body);
```

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814857/retrofit-2-with-only-form-data/37831830) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image)

Comment: not solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code to call API.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/search-result")
Call<Frame>  getSearchResult(@Field("property_type[]") String[] propertyType,
                     @Field("bedroom_type[]") String[] bedroomType);
```