# Problems Sending FormUrlEncoded using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have this request and I need to send it by FormUrlEncoded using Retrofit

```
{
   "clnt_id": "OQW",
   "clnt_res": "AA!@#$T",
   "type": "SCDS",
   "len": "ASD"
}
```

I used this code:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Endpoint")
    @Headers("Accept: Application/JSON")
    fun connect(
        @Field("clnt_id") clnt_id: String,
        @Field(value = "clnt_res", encoded = false) clnt_res: String,
        @Field("type") type: String,
        @Field("len") len: String
    ): Observable<Token>
```

First, thing is that the request is not sent as JSON

Second, the value of "clnt_res", encoded by retrofit

Comment: remove the header type and try again

Comment: Did not work ...

Comment: kindly update the log file ...

Comment: Which log file, I am not understand

Comment: You can't send json with `FormUrlEncoded` use @Body

Comment: The error log which gets it from retrofit or android crash log

Comment: True, but the backend required me to use form-data

Comment: Try to send request with `Postman`. If everything is correct then try with retrofit.

Comment: In postman the request has done successfully

Comment: But in retrofit nothing success

Comment: What did you check in `Body` section in `Postman`?

Comment: Body => form-data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49974050/8942811

Comment: @Bek did not work man :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get the answer and it was a problem with symbol `'$'` in `'clnt_res'` value `"AA!@#$T"`, The problem is in kotlin to escape a special char you need to do this `"\$"`, what I made the IDE didn't tell me that it is wrong is this `"$/"`.

Comment: Still not Resolved in  Java, I am coping value from a TextView. If anyone enters '@' character, it gets converted to '%40'

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to send json request from android using Retrofit.

1. Create Pojo Model of json request and pass it by setting values of it.
2. Create HashMap and pass it to request.

Here is solution using 2nd Method:

Create hashmap and put key(parameters) and value:

```
Map<String,String> requestMap = new HashMap<>();
        requestMap.put("clnt_id","your_value");
        requestMap.put("clnt_res","your_value");
        requestMap.put("type","your_value");
        requestMap.put("len","your_value");
```

Then pass it to your retrofit request using FieldMap:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Endpoint")
    @Headers("Accept: Application/JSON")
    fun connect(
        @FieldMap requestMap:Map<String,String>
    ): Observable<Token>
```

Comment: I try second method, but nothing change, it is like my code no difference just you created a Map instead of Fields And the value of "clnt_res" is still encoded by retrofit

Comment: is it working in postman?? can you please show me how do you call in postman??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202198/discussion-between-vishal-thakkar-and-a-albrg).