# Retrofit Calling the Magneto API using @FormUrlEncoded getting issue while sending the data to the magneto server

Tags: android, retrofit2, magento2

override fun submitSupportTicket(createSupportTicket: MutableLiveData,
question: String,
details: String,
department: String,
filePath: String) {
var getSupporttUrl = "https://xxxxxxxx/V1/ecomapi/postNewSupportTicket"
if (filePath.isEmpty()) {
/* var getDepartmentInput = Constants.getDefaultParameterJasonInput(Constants.getUserId())
getDepartmentInput.put("questionText",question)
getDepartmentInput.put("detailText",details)
getDepartmentInput.put("departmentId",department)*/

```
       /* val requestMap: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        requestMap["questionText"] = String(question.toByteArray(), charset("UTF-8"))
        requestMap["detailText"] = String(details.toByteArray(), charset("UTF-8"))
        requestMap["departmentId"] = String(department.toByteArray(), charset("UTF-8"))
        requestMap["customerId"] = String(Constants.getUserId().toByteArray(), charset("UTF-8"))

        val dataSupport = CreateSupportTicketModel(String(question.toByteArray(), charset("UTF-8")),
                String(details.toByteArray(), charset("UTF-8")),
                String(department.toByteArray(), charset("UTF-8")),
                String(Constants.getUserId().toByteArray(), charset("UTF-8")))

        val request = Gson().toJson(dataSupport)

        val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        params["data"] = request*/

        val bodyQuestion: RequestBody = RequestBody.create("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull(), question)
        val bodyDetails: RequestBody = RequestBody.create("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull(), details)
        val bodyDepartment: RequestBody = RequestBody.create("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull(), department)
        val bodyUserId: RequestBody = RequestBody.create("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull(), Constants.getUserId())


        mView.getAPIComponent().retroService.getBaseUrl()
                .createSupportTicketWithoutImage(Constants.getHeaderTokenForApisWithCType(),
                        getSupporttUrl, bodyQuestion,bodyDetails,bodyDepartment,bodyUserId
                )
                .enqueue(object : CustomRetroCallbacks<Any>() {

                    override fun onSuccess(resonse: Any?) {
                        createSupportTicket.value = resonse
                    }

                    override fun onError(response: Any?) {
```

//                            createSupportTicket.value = response?.message
}

```
                    override fun onFailure(generalErrorMsg: String, systemErrorMsg: String) {
                        mView.getDepartmentListFailed(generalErrorMsg)
                    }
                })

    } else {
        var imagePart: MultipartBody.Part? = null
        if (!Utility.isBlankString(filePath)) {
            val imageFile = File(filePath)
            val inputStream = mView.context(true).contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(imageFile))
            imagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("attachment[]", imageFile.name, imageFile.toImagePartBody())
        }

        val requestBodyQuestion: RequestBody = question.toRequestBody("*/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val requestBodyDepartment: RequestBody = department.toRequestBody("*/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val requestBodyDetails: RequestBody = details.toRequestBody("*/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val requestBodyUserId: RequestBody = Constants.getUserId().toRequestBody("*/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())


        mView.getAPIComponent().retroService.getBaseUrl()
                .createSupportTicket(Constants.getHeaderTokenForApisWithCType(), getSupporttUrl,
                        imagePart,
                        requestBodyQuestion,
                        requestBodyDetails,
                        requestBodyDepartment,
                        requestBodyUserId)
                .enqueue(object : CustomRetroCallbacks<Any>() {

                    override fun onSuccess(resonse: Any?) {
                        createSupportTicket.value = resonse
                        createSupportTicket.value = false
                    }

                    override fun onError(response: Any?) {
                        createSupportTicket.value = false
```

//                            createSupportTicket.value = response?.message
}

```
                    override fun onFailure(generalErrorMsg: String, systemErrorMsg: String) {
                        createSupportTicket.value = false
                        mView.getDepartmentListFailed(generalErrorMsg)
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

**API INTERFACE**

```
@POST
@Multipart
fun createSupportTicketWithoutImage(@HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>,
                                    @Url url: String?,
                                    @Part("questionText ") questionText:RequestBody,
                                    @Part("detailText ") detailText:RequestBody,
                                    @Part("departmentId ") departmentId:RequestBody,
                                    @Part("customerId ") customerId:RequestBody ): Call<Any>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question?

Comment: Show us you function please

Comment: @MohammadKhairPK I am edited my question and share the code

Comment: Show me the endPinot please

Comment: @MohammadKhairPK var getSupporttUrl="https://xxxxxxxx/V1/ecomapi/postNewSupportTicket"

Comment: No, I mean the function which calling the end pint (the interface)

Comment: @MohammadKhairPK I have added in question. Please check

Comment: You have to pass the end point in the   **@POST("login")ex**

Comment: **@FormUrlEncoded** Denotes that the request body will use form URL encoding. Fields should be declared as parameters and annotated with @Field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225827/discussion-between-peter-and-mohammad-khair-pk).