# Retrofit 2 Server not Receiving POST Android

Tags: php, android, api, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2 to get some data from PHP API. The server receives the call, however, $_POST is empty!

I tried sending data using various ways, but still no luck!

here is sample php api

```
<?php

$token = $_POST["api_token"];

$myObj = new stdClass();
$myObj -> api_token = $token;

$jsonObj = json_encode($myObj);
echo $jsonObj;
?>
```

I tried calling api using postman (working fine)

[image]

here is my Client interface `ClientTester`

```
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface ClientTester {
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    @POST("/****/****.php")
    Call<ResponseTester> postParams(
             @Body Map<String, String> requestBody);
}
```

Also, this is response class `ResponseTester`

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ResponseTester {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("api_token")
    private String apiToken;

    public String getApiToken() {
        return apiToken;
    }

    public void setApiToken(String apiToken) {
        this.apiToken = apiToken;
    }
}
```

and my request function

```
    private void sendRequest() {

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://****.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    ClientTester ClientTester = retrofit.create(ClientTester.class);
    Call<ResponseTester> call = ClientTester.postParams(getBodyParams());

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseTester>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseTester> call, Response<ResponseTester> response) {

            Log.d("VolleyResponse", "onResponse: " + response.body().getApiToken());
            tvResponse.setText(response.body().getApiToken()+"...");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseTester> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("VolleyResponse", "onFailure: " + t.toString());
            tvResponse.setText(t.toString());

        }
    });


private Map<String, String> getBodyParams() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("api_token", "SomeToken");
    return params;
}
```

Unfortunately, `response.body().getApiToken()` returns null!

by the way, I tried other solutions like,
. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37831830/5193899

EDIT,

My problem is with the android app, as the API works fine with iOS app and API testers, this solution doesn’t solve my problem as it requires a change to API code!

[Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: unfortunately no. My problem is with the android app, as the API works fine with iOS app and API testers, this solution may solve my problem, but it requires a change to API code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have the content type set to `application/json`

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    @POST("/****/****.php")
    Call<ResponseTester> postParams(
             @Body Map<String, String> requestBody);
```

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) `$_POST` only returns

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `multipart/form-data`
- `text/plain`

In order to read the token from PHP you have 2 options.

You can either

- Remove the header annotation at `postParams`
- Use this code to read `application/json` in PHP.

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_data = json_decode($data , true);
$token = $json_data['api_token'];
```

Comment: `$_JSON`? I think you mean `$_POST` there.

Comment: I just tried your solution, and it is working super fine,

my only concern is that I didn't make the API, and that was just a sample, is there a way to solve this problem form android code itself?

Comment: @CBroe yes you are right, it was a typo, I will edit my awnser

Comment: @Joseph Ali if you remove the @Headers({...})  Annotation in `ClientTester`  it should work without changing the API

Comment: @Joseph Ali I edited my awnser to explain it better

Comment: Before asking the question i tried removing the headers, but didn't work, anyways your answer is perfect.