# How to pass pdf form-data body with Retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

[image]

I want to upload a pdf file with other fields using Retrofit2. But I don't know how to create a request body for it.

```
  @POST("filebase/upload")
suspend fun uploadPdfDocument(@Header(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION) authorization: String, @Body requestBody: RequestBody): UploadPdfDocumetResponse?
```

Please help me!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37831830/10479081

Answer (score 1):

If in your dependencies exists okhttp3 then you can use this beautiful extenstion function

```
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.asRequestBody

yourPdfFile.asRequestBody(yourPdfFile.getExtension())
```

`getExtension()` function below

```
fun File.getExtension(): MediaType? {
    var type: String? = null
    val encoded: String = try {
        URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        name
    }
    val extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(encoded)
    if (extension != null) {
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
    }

    return type?.toMediaType()
}
```