# How to post string array using POSTMAN?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am using Postman to send an array of string to a web API. The web API method looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IEnumerable<DocumentDTO>> GetDocuments([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> documentNames)
{
    return await _service.GetDocuments(documentNames);
}
```

I saw this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension) on how to send an array using Postman. Here is how I am sending the array:
[image]

Fiddler shows the request's content type is `multipart/form-data;`

[image]

But I am getting an error response:

> {   "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data'
>   is not supported for this resource.",   "ExceptionMessage": "No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type
>   'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.", 
>   "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
>
>   "StackTrace": "   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)" }

I have tried setting the key as `documentNames`,`documentNames[]`, `documentNames[0]`.

I have tried selecting the body as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. When I do that, the API receives an empty collection.

I have tried selecting a body as `raw`. When I do that, the API receives null as a parameter.

**Questions**

1. How do I send a string array using form-data?
2. How do I send a string array using `x-www-form-urlencoded`?
3. How do I send a string array as raw JSON?

Answer (score 28):

Pass it as JSON array and select the `raw` option like below

[image]

For a API method signature

```
    public void Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<string> value)
    {
      //some processing
    }
```

Comment: Thank you , I used same idea for list of complex objects and it works fine for me

Comment: so simple and I was fiddling with it for such a long time. it came to my surprise that passing it as { value:[1,2,3] } cannot be recognized by the request handler.

Answer (score 19):

if you want to initialize an array via params, you can do that.

#### use a `variable` with a same name

[image]

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: @AnmolJain This worked for me and many others. Please check your code. In case you find better way than this, post a comment and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use same key in form remember add [] on it
[image]

Comment: adding[] works, specially when we json_encode to save it as a string in our database.
if you do `categories[0]` / `categories[1]` it will create key value pairs and the value arriving at the server will not be in a single array