# Posting a List of GUIDs to a MVC 5 Controller with Postman

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, postman

I'm attempting to make a controller method:

```
public String CreateGasolineBlend(List<Guid> enumerableTransferIDs)
    {
        //Details
    }
```

Accept a list of GUIDs. However, the list is always null when I'm using postman.

I tried using this article to find out how to format the request:

[Is it possible to send an array with the Postman Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension)

But I'm unsure if MVC even is capable of accepting a List of objects using a Post Method, or if perhaps I am incorrectly formatting the POST request in Postman.

(I am using what the previous stack overflow question states, arr[0], arr[1] or arr[], arr[] with Guids as values.)

Is my problem with the way I'm receiving the values in the controller, or is it a problem with how I'm using Postman?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MVC is capable of accepting a list objects and map it to the action method parameter.

You need to make sure you are using the correct `Content-Type` header value when send the data. `"application/json"` should work.

I just updated your action method to return the posted data along with the item count in a json structure to verify this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateGasolineBlend(List<Guid> enumerableTransferIDs)
{
    return Json(new { ItemCount= enumerableTransferIDs.Count(),
                      Items= enumerableTransferIDs});
}
```

You can see the response came back with the data we posted.

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem exactly. I'm fairly new to MVC and web development, so I had no idea that there was a difference between sending form data as opposed to raw / application/json. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.