# Json Deserialize error. Unsupported type of : System.Guid

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I was working on an API project, and got below issue,

this is the Json I'm passing

```
{
  "MainClass": [
    {
      "Text": ".",
      "Id": {
        "System.Guid": "06073a9c-9cef-4f07-9180-2e54e0fa6416"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my c# Models

```
public class MainClass {
  public List<SubClass> Subs {get;set;}
}

public class SubClass {
  public string Text {get;set;}
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
}
```

When i pass the above json i'm getting below error

> {
>       "Message": "The request is invalid.",
>       "ModelState": {
>           "MainClass.SubClass [0].Id": [
>               "Json Deserialize error. Unsupported type of : System.Guid"
>           ]
>       } }

I have tried below Json also,

```
{
  "MainClass": [
    {
      "Text": ".",
      "Id": "06073a9c-9cef-4f07-9180-2e54e0fa6416"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i fix it?

This happens when i post the json using postman. I can see that it hits the controller, but not the action. It throws error saying as above.

Comment: I added my answer below with output and online demo, try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** For your first json,

```
{
  "MainClass": [
    {
      "Text": ".",
      "Id": {
        "System.Guid": "06073a9c-9cef-4f07-9180-2e54e0fa6416"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to create one more class model to hold the property of type Guid,

```
public class RootClass
{
    public List<MainClass> MainClass { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public _Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class _Guid
{
    [JsonProperty("System.Guid")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
RootClass mainClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(json);

mainClass.MainClass.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Text:\t" + x.Text + "\n" + "Id:\t" + x.Id.Id));
```

[## Online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J0sT0R)

---

**2)** And for your second json,

```
{
  "MainClass": [
    {
      "Text": ".",
      "Id": "06073a9c-9cef-4f07-9180-2e54e0fa6416"
    }
  ]
}
```

You need below class hierarchy to deserialize your json correctly,

```
public class RootClass
{
    public List<MainClass> MainClass { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }       //<= The type "System.Guid" as it is
}
```

**Usage:**

```
RootClass mainClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(json);

mainClass.MainClass.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Text:\t" + x.Text + "\n" + "Id:\t" + x.Id));
```

[## Online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bgsL6T)

---

**Output:** (For both above json)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you require following class files

```
public class Id
{
    [JsonProperty("System.Guid")]
    public string System_Guid { get; set; }
}


public class MainClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Id Id { get; set; }
}

public class rootClass
{
    public List<MainClass> MainClass { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: System.Guid cannot be string variable so it requires to be replaced by _

Comment: Thanks for the input, But https://stackoverflow.com/a/39733825/6915387 says guid will be automatically mapped, right?

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [json generator](http://json2csharp.com/) like this objects

And so,result is that

```
public class Id
{
    public string MyGuid { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Id Id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<MainClass> MainClass { get; set; }
}
```

You can not use System.Guid name as property name.

**IMPORTANT** : Deserialize object like this;

```
RootObject myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.Replace("System.Guid","MyGuid"));
```

Comment: System.Guid can't be variable name