# how to accept array of parameters in body in nodejs

Tags: node.js

My orderschema is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var foodtruck = require('./foodtruck.js');
var payment = require('./payment.js');
var Items = require('./items.js');


var order = new Schema({
    order_status:Number,   //0 place 1 accepted 2 cooked 3 cancelled
    customer_id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'user'},
    items:[{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'items'}],
    user_type:Boolean,
    order_time:Date,
    order_rating:{type:Number,default:5.0},
    order_issue_comments:String,
    order_special_instruction:String,
    order_total:Number,
    order_location:String,
    order_coupon_code:String,
    payment_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'payment'}
},{ versionKey: false });


module.exports = mongoose.model('order',order);
```

items.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    no_of_times_ordered:Number,
    item_name:String,
    item_tag:String,
    item_category:String,
    item_illustrations:[String],
    item_stock:Number,
    item_quantity_ordered:{type:Number,default:0},
    item_price:Number,
    item_img:String,
    no_of_likes:Number
},{ versionKey: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model('items',ItemSchema);
```

Now in my **items** parameter, I am expecting an array. I have already achieved the successful order creation with only one item. But I am unable to put **item** array while making request in postman.

The following line are from the postman request

```
customer_id:58b9aaca50fb632134fc78f5
order_special_instruction:please add onions
order_total:50.09
order_location:seattle
order_coupon_code:AERT78
payment_id:58b9aaca50fb632134fc79a7
item_id:58ba7ae503f5cc2bf48d6932
item_quantity:2
```

Now how would I have multiple **item_id** and **item_quantity** in request. The parameters that I have posted above are accepted in "x-www-form-urlencoded" in postman.

Comment: I think you posted the wrong code for `items.js` ☺️

Comment: I have updated code for **item.js** in question.

Comment: Can you show your request body while requesting with postman

Comment: I have updated postman request parameters in my question

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension

Comment: Thanks for help. Now i can enter item_id[0],item_id[1] etc. but when I try to access them through req.body.item_id[0] , it gives me error

Comment: verify your results with: for (var key in req.body) {
  if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    item = req.body[key];
    console.log(item);
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the discussion in comments, I suggest to use a body parser such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser to make your life easier.