# How to get and process Input for django-multiselectfield in Django rest framework via form-data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multichoiceitems

I have `User` model with `food_prefrence` field for which a user has the option to select multiple choices.

In models, I am using `MultiSelectField` from [django-multiselectfield](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) to solve my problem. and in my User serializer, I am using fields.MultipleChoiceField provided by rest-framework.

now my problem is how to get input from the user using form-data and how to process that in my view or serializer, as of now when I am trying to insert choices **using postman with form-data** selected, this is giving me an error when `serializer.is_valid()` is called

```
{
    "food_preference": [
        "\"'Indian', 'Continental'\" is not a valid choice."
    ]
}
```

below is my code snippet.

```
#models.py
class User(AbstractUser, BaseClass):
    food_preference = MultiSelectField(_('Food Preference'), choices=CONST_Food, blank=True, null=True)

#serializer.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    food_preference = fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CONST_Food, required=False)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.food_preference = validated_data.get('food_preference', instance.food_preference)
    instance.save()
    return instance, "Updated Successfully"

#views.py
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={"request": self.request})
    print(serializer.initial_data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True): ##<<<<<Execution stops here
        print("is valid")
        result = serializer.update(instance=instance, validated_data=request.data)
        if result[0] is None:
            return _error_response(400, EPHISH, result[1], {})
        data = self.serializer_class(result[0], context={"request": self.request}).data
        return _response(data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return _einval_serializer_response(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, self.serializer_class)
```

also here is the screenshot from my postman
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And in DRF i changed the field to:

food_preference = fields.CharField(required=False)

Then i was good to go.

Comment: this is definitively the work around. i added  `fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES)` in my serializer as mentioned in https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/  and i did not worked. this is weird!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like

```
CONST_Food= (
        (1, 'One'),
        (2, 'Two'),
        (3, 'Three')
    )
```

Then you have to send 1,2,3.

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

So the idea is to send values.

**Update**

Oh, finally I got this! You are using django-multiselectfield (please add it to the tags, so if someone will have the same problem he will find the solution faster) I've replicated your configuration and first of all instead of

```
CONST_Food= (
            (1, 'One'),
            (2, 'Two'),
            (3, 'Three')
        )
```

your tuple have to look like

```
CONST_Food= (
            ('1', 'One'),
            ('2', 'Two'),
            ('3', 'Three')
        )
```

The problem was in the serializer that expects list of strings, but you was sending the list of integers and/or values itself that it can't parse. 
So your JSON will be

```
{
...
    "food_preference": ["1", "3"]
...
}
```

Comment: Tried that, giving same error. 1 & 2  is not a valid choice

Comment: I tried adding django-multiselectfield as tag, but don't have enough reputation to create new tag. You see.

Comment: @SumeetKumar Please show your CONST_Food and your JSON that you are sending

Comment: not sending in JSON format, but in `multipart/form-data`, as my original serializer contain images and also i am using parser for that.

Comment: @SumeetKumar Please check this, now I'm not sure that this qustion is related to the drf or django but postman https://stackoverflow.com/a/23735006/7396169

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from yourapp.models import YourModel

class YourModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    your_multiselect_field = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=YourModel.YOUR_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

List item

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**