# How to access array values in Postman using python

Tags: python, postman

I came across this question that was asked a while back to send array data in postman ([Is it possible to send an array with the Postman Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension)).

My problem is though, I want to be able to access all those variables sent. Currently, I'm only receiving the first one because I say:
key=shareholder, value=100

If I try

```
key=shareholder[0], value=100     
key=shareholder[1], value=200
```

or even without the indexes,then I get a NONETYPE error for shareholder

code:

```
request_data={
    "shareholder": []
}
request_data["shareholder"].append(int(request.form.get("shareholder")))
```

Would definitely appreciate the help. Sorry if anything I said is unclear

Answer (score 0):

To access a variable in Postman is incredibly easy. BUT, Postman is Javascript application. You need to use python nowhere with postman. Javascript is a comprehensive one.
I didn't get what kind of variable you want to access, but if you give me a clear example I will tell you how to reach any level of variable in postman
MORE INFO:
[https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables](http://variables)