# Array of ObjectId with ref in mongoose show error Cast to Array failed for value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm creating a blog schema with array of category id,but when i try to insert data on field it's show

**category_id: Cast to Array failed for value "[\'5c8a207e36e3613fe9a6ce30\',\'5c8a207e36e3613fe9a6ce30\']" at path "category_id"**

my schema is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    user_id:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    },
    category_id:{
        type:[mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref:'Categories',
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    is_featured:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    isActive:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:true
    },
    created_at:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    },
    updated_at:{
        type:String
    }
});

var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog',blogSchema);

module.exports.Blog = Blog;
```

also i try

```
category_id:[{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Categories',
    }],
```

but getting same error

Comment: when you are inserting into collection are you using id as objectid or string?
id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5c8a207e36e3613fe9a6ce30');

Comment: i'm using postman and send id like that

 "category_id":"['5c8a207e36e3613fe9a6ce30','5c8a207e36e3613fe9a6ce30']",

Comment: ohh, you need to parse the array in your code as "[]" is a string. or use 
"category_id":['5c8a207e36e3613fe9a6ce30','5c8a207e36e3613fe9a6ce30']

Comment: or try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension

Comment: @AZ_ not clear understand your answer, as i understand i'm sending array using 
"[]"

Comment: everything inside the quote " is a string so as "[]", if you want to insert an array you may need to remove the quotes. so it must be "category_id":['5c8a207e36e3613fe9a6ce30','5c8a207e36e3613fe9a6ce30']

Comment: Thank you @AZ_ this is the problem in api data, now it's working fine