# Foreach loop is showing error on adding members in group

Tags: php, laravel, postman, grouping

I am trying to create a group using Postman. What I am doing is, I am adding group name and members in it. Firstly I am adding name in one table and adding the id of that group with members in another table. But don't know why its creating error in Foreach Loop .i.e `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Here is my code in controller:

```
public function createGroup(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'name'=>'required',
    ];

    $result = $this->validate_request($request->all(), $rules);
    if(!empty($result)) return $this->sendErrorResponse($result);  

    $user_id = request('user_id');
    $member = request('member');

    $data = array(
        'name'=>$request->name,  
    );

    $group = Group::create($data);

    if($group->id)
    {      
        foreach($member as $m)
        {
            GroupUser::create([
                'group_id' => $group->id,
                'user_id' => $m,
                'status' => 0,
            ]);
        }                
        
        return $this->sendSuccessResponse([
            'message'=>ResponseMessage::statusResponses(ResponseMessage::_STATUS_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Please let me know, where I am missing

[image]

Comment: $member seems to be the problem, so you can use dd($member) to see what the variable contains;

Comment: As you suggest, it gives me last member id

Comment: you can not perform a foreach on a single thing. you must provide an array of ids.

Comment: how can we add, can you please update my code

Comment: You will have to show where the data is coming from. how/where is request('member') filled. now it is just 1 id, it should be an array

Comment: I have added the screenshot above, that how I am entering the data

Comment: if you want to post an array, the name must include a bracket, so member[] instead of member (the same rule applies in a regular html form)

Comment: I have done with HTML forms and its working perfect but its creating problem while working on Postman for APIs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to send an array with the Postman Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension)

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Postman itself, or to whatever you mean by [tag:grouping]? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass raw JSON from Postman like this

```
{
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "members": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

Also since I'm here your code needs a little refactoring. First, it would be good to create a Form Request for validation and put your validation logic there.

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'name' => ['required'],
    'group_id' => ['numeric', 'exists:groups,id'],
    'members' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
  ];
}
```

So then your controller could look like

```
public function createGroup(YourNewRequest $request)
{
  $group = Group::create([$request->name]);

  if($request->group_id){      
    foreach($request->members as $member){
      $group->user->attach($member);
    }                
        
    return $this->sendSuccessResponse([
      'message'=>ResponseMessage::statusResponses(ResponseMessage::_STATUS_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS)
    ]);
  }
}
```

I might have misunderstood some of your code's logic but this is to give you a rough idea what you can do.