# How to send array via postman in POST request

Tags: django-rest-framework, postman

I want to  send array via postman in POST request. I want to send data like this

```
{
    "users": [1, 2]
}
```

I read this post [Is it possible to send an array with the Postman Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension)

and reproduced, but received an error (see image).
**How can i fix the error?**

I am using django rest framework and server answered that

```
request["users"] is None
```

[image]

Comment: does the endpoint expect json or formdata ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot send array through formdata , if your endpoint expects json then send it as body>raw>json:

[image]

Comment: thank you, it helped me. But is it possible to use "from-data" ?

Comment: form data doesn't support array