# How to send array of objects in postman form data and and receive as array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

In postman, I have done in form-data  KEY -products VALUE-

```
[
  { name: "Pizza", price: "10", quantity: "7" },
  { name: "Cerveja", price: "12", quantity: "5" },
  { name: "Hamburguer", price: "10", quantity: "2" },
  { name: "Fraldas", price: "6", quantity: "2" },
];
```

In code,I want to receive this same array of objects but I can receive it as a string. My code is

```
var products =req.body.products;
console.log(typeof(products))//string shows
var Products=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products))
console.log(typeof(Products))// it also string shows
```

if I print array 0 index value it prints "[" array bracket
Please Help me out I am new in this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have ask duplicate question
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension)! that solution worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Since `products` is a string, you only need to parse this into an object with `JSON.parse()`

Use `JSON.stringify()` when u want to convert a javascript object to a string.

So:

```
var products = JSON.parse(req.body.products); // parse string to object
console.log(products[0]); // will output the pizza
```