# How to pass query parameter or form parameter having array items so that all options should get pass

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a request which have multiple form parameters. One of the form parameters is in below format:

```
"DistributionChoices": ["ABC.com", "JPQ.com", "N\A"]
```

When I am doing post request with queryParams and passing:

```
queryParam.put("DistributionChoices", Arrays.asList("ABC.com", "JPQ.com", "N\A"));
```

or

```
formParam("DistributionChoices", Arrays.asList("ABC.com", "JPQ.com", "N\A"));
```

Then it is selecting only the first value, i.e. ABC.com

The field is a multichoice which accepts all values.

How can I pass all values in this parameter?

Note: In Postman, it works fine if I pass it like this:

```
 "DistributionChoices": ["ABC.com", "JPQ.com", "N\A"]
```

Language: Java
Framework: RestAssured along with TestNG

Code:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("ABC.com", "JPQ.com", "N\A");

RestAssured.base = "baseURI";
Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
queryParams.put("apiKey","apiKeyValue");
queryParams.put("name","nameValue");
queryParams.put("description","descriptionValue");

queryParams.put("distrbutionChoice",items); // Here is the issue

RestAssured.given().params(queryParams);

Response response = request.when().post();
```

Output: This takes the first value from the item list.

Answer (score 1):

To send a formParam with an array of values, the key must be suffixed by `[]`.

So for your example, this should work:

```
formParam("DistributionChoices[]", Arrays.asList("ABC.com", "JPQ.com", "N\A"));
```

Getting the request working in PostMan gave me the clue: [Is it possible to send an array with the Postman Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension)

Comment: Not in the project anymore, else would have tried it. Anyway,  I post the entire request as in body at that moment and handled it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is exactly the format which it needs to be sent as,
but a  quick guess would be: `DistributionChoices=["ABC.com", "JPQ.com", "N\A"]`.

So, in order to parse the list to this format do the following:

```
var value = "[\"" + String.join("\", \"", Arrays.asList("ABC.com", "JPQ.com", "N\\A")) + "\"]";
queryParam.put("DistributionChoices", value)
```

This is simply adding a comma between every word in this list, and wrapping these in brackets. (JSON format)

Comment: It didn't work out. It throws error by saying invalid parameter and value inserted like this:                  \"[ABC.com,JPQ.com,N\A]""

Comment: I've updated the code now it will add the quotes around the String.
If it still does not work, please tell me what is the expected input so I can provide a precise solution.

Comment: It didn't work.  It's an array.  It should go like this : [\"ABC.com\", \"ABC\", \"The HULK\", \"India US UK\"]   But when We enter it like this, it append \" in begining and \"" in the end. I am using it inside a map of <String, Object>

Comment: Code is added as requested.