# How to send array of object using postman as a formdata

Tags: rest, post, postman, multipartform-data

I am trying to send an array of the object as a form-data using postman. But it's not working. I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Header%20and%20select,and%20then%20pass%20an%20array.) in StackOverflow...But it's worked for mt.

[image]

When I send my category like this it's sent like this:- Category returns null property.
[image]

This should be like this. I got this screenshot when I was passing data application/JSON.
[image]

But now I need to send an image with my req, I need to send my req as a form/data. But My Category object array is not passing the way I want, Or the way my system wants. I really need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you found the answer to this?

Comment: @Arvind suresh Update my answere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found Solutions by myself. You can send the request like this.

[image].

Comment: what should be the content type and how to handle this array in nodejs?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily send an array or array of objects as form-data in postman, using this approach.

1. Add normal key-value pair as shown, make sure the array is in it's raw format.
   [image: A key value pair of an array]
2. On the server use this method to receive the array.
   [image]

This should work!!

Comment: Please do not post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 2):

[list of json objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08TjE.png)

I'll leave this here might help someone , since all didn't work for me except this one .

```
prizes[0]name => iPhone 14 pro
prizes[0]count => 5
prizes[1]name => iPhone 15
prizes[1]count => 3
prizes[2]name => iPhone 15 Pro Max
prizes[2]count => 1
```

the structure will be like

```
prizes = [
{
"name": "iPhone 14 pro",
"count": 5
},
{
"name": "iPhone 15",
"count": 3
},
{
"name": "iPhone 15 Pro Max",
"count": 1
}
]
```

Comment: Please do not add images of code or data. Instead [edit] your post and write directly into the post.

Answer (score 0):

Without the array index also work
[image]