# How to handle multipart/form-data requests with a file array field wrapped in another class, with SpringBoot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, postman, multipartform-data

Given the following Java class:

```
@Data
public class Student {
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private List<MultipartFile> photos;
}
```

I would like to create an API endpoint as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFiles(@RequestPart("students") List<Student> students) throws IOException {
        // code to process the request.
    }
```

Am I doing this correctly? The application starts up without an issue but I am not sure how to use Postman to test the endpoint. Do I need to use @ModelAttribute and an HTML form for this purpose?

I tried to follow a variant of the accepted solution in the given thread but in vain: [How to send array of object using postman as a formdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062232/how-to-send-array-of-object-using-postman-as-a-formdata)