# Send array via postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I would like to send array of id's via postman

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGMPU.png)

I looked on to above thread, for me array[] /array[0] didn't work out,
using same key with different value worked for me.
[image: Postman file]

It gave [image]

But I am not able to send single element in array or an empty array.

I see it in req.body as a string of characters

So how should I send it?

Comment: I also tried sending data as raw and also changed the content-type to application/json, I tried to console.log my req body but I got it empty {}

Answer (score 0):

So I just needed to set extended option of urlencoded to true and use arr[0] in postman, and it worked for me.

just make `express.urlencoded({extended : true});`
it was set to false before and arr[] or arr[0] didnot worked.